# Loading 2000 characters text inside a .js versus loading in the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, performance

I have a website with the typical footer "About Me", "About this site", ... and when the user clicks any of those, a modal/popup is displayed and its innerHTML set via JavaScript

```
var aboutMe = "I am Foo and I like ..."; // 500 characters;
var aboutTheSite = "This site is for ..."; // 500 characters;
var cookiePolicy = "This site uses cookies ..."; // 500 characters;
// ...
// ...
```

The alternative for doing this is to create some tags and append that text

```
<div id='aboutMeContent'>I am Foo and I like ... </div>
<!-- ... .... more -->
```

I didn't do the second option because I like to keep my source code really clean ([YouTubeGo.net](http://YouTubeGo.net)). But I am a bit worried about this worsening the performance of the site. All the JavaScript is minimized in a 30K file, but without `aboutMe`, `aboutThisSite`... it would be 20K, though those 10K would be loaded inside the `.html`.

---

The question:
**Which of both options is better?

Or would it still preferable to load it using AJAX and forget about what I am doing?**

And a little more technical question (I'm curious):
Does a browser load faster a JavaScript file with only `var foo = "fooBar";` and variable declarations than one with really dense code? I know from experience that it doesn't read the contents of an object or a function until it is called or requested.

I care very much about performance time but I can't tell you what was I thinking when I implemented the first option.

Comment: You probably want to remove your intrusive event handlers...

Comment: What about profiling this within Chrome's debugger (Ctrl+Shift+J) and testing which loads faster?

Comment: Intrusive for what you've just read or because you have been digging in my website? Excuse me, but I don't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: @Nico "Intrusive" referring to the practice of embedding Javascript in your HTML via `onclick` attributes and the like. To clean up your source, you ought to add event listeners after the page has loaded, from your Javascript itself, without messing up your HTML.

Comment: Okay, I thought intrusive JS was `<a href="javascript:fooBar()">Click!</a>`, which is why I corrected about 100 of those at my workplace. Since `onclick` is invisible to the average user and I consider that listeners overload the browser...

Comment: I have been very careful with the event listeners in the website to try adding the least possible. But am I assuming wrong about browser capacities?